# javascript image rollover not just on image, but on empty sides too

Tags: javascript, css, html

The rollover works on the image itself, changing from one image to another then back again, but the problem is that it the image also changes on each side of the image on rollover where there is blank space.

I know there it can be done better in CSS, but it is a school assignment and must be in javascript.  Below is the code in HTML, then what I have for it in CSS

**HTML**

```
<script>
imageout=new Image();
imageout.src="Pics/Image1.jpg";
imageover=new Image();
imageover.src="Pics/Image2.jpg";

function image_out(){
document.images['imageout'].src="Pics/Image1.jpg";
}

function image_over(){
document.images['imageout'].src="Pics/Image2.jpg";
}
</script>

<a href="javascript-rollover-image-swap.htm" onmouseover="image_over();"
onmouseout="image_out();"><img src="Pics/Image1.jpg" class="center"
id="imageout" width="400" height="200" alt="JavaScript rollover. Image swap"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If someone can point out my error or if there is a better way to do this (must be javascript), I would certainly appreciate it!

Comment: `the problem is that it the image also changes on each side of the image on rollover where there is blank space`. not able to understand your problem. do you have any fiddle or snippet or the image screenshot showing your problem. I just added your code in fiddle and it is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/s9rf88mn/22/

Comment: The rollover works fine, but the image changes if the mouse is next to it. Lemme try to explain again    |     mouse       image      |   

Where you see the word mouse, that causes the image to change, not just when the mouse is actually over the image.  How do I get images to load in fiddle?  I just created an account there.  Or how do I load a screenshot here?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I just looked at the fiddle you did.  The image changes when the mouse is on either side of the image, not just when the mouse rolls over the image.  That is what I am trying to fix, not changing the image when the mouse is on the side.  Hope that makes a little more sense

Comment: It's the `display: block;` in the `img` that is expanding the `a`. I'd do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/83nbka0v/10/). I was also wondering if you need javascript for this? The example you gave makes me think you could just use a css `:hover` to change the background image.

Comment: @Joonas that is what I needed.  Yes, it does have to be in javascript, it is for a class assignment.  I must admit though, I am a bit confused regarding the display:block part.  I guess I am not understanding the differences in the code

Comment: @BradAnderson that is because of the block elements will cover the entire row. if you don't want then remove the class `center` from anchor tag or change like `.center{display:inline-block}`

Comment: What Suresh said pretty much covers it, but if you take a look at [this (and scroll down a bit) you can see a visual example of this behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai and Joonas you have both been a big help.  I understand things much better now!  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment, block level elements will cover the entire row, So remove the class `center` from your anchor tag and If you want to align the items in middle then change your structure of html like below.

```
<div class="center">
     <a href="javascript-rollover-image-swap.htm" onmouseover="image_over();"onmouseout="image_out();">
        <img src="https://www.delecta.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" id="imageout" width="400" height="200" alt="JavaScript rollover. Image swap">
     </a>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s9rf88mn/27/)